# UIButton action method is not doing anything

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

UIButton Action method not showing  any results when executing. Basically UIButton by default shows Bookmark-N image when UIButton is pressed it should replace Bookmark-N with Bookmark-YES image.

When pressing UIButton it is not replacing image infact not doing anything.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bookmarkbtn;

- (IBAction)bookmarkAction:(id)sender;


- (IBAction)bookmarkAction:(id)sender {

if ( _bookmarkbtn.tag)

{
    [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else 
{
    [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

I think something has to do with this statement

```
if ( _bookmarkbtn.tag)
```

Because this statement if it is true only then it will execute rest.

Any ideas please how to fix this statement.

Comment: Did you connect the button to the ibaction in interface builder?

Comment: Edit: what happens when you put a breakpoint on the if? What is the value of 'tag', it is an nsinteger btw, not a boolean.

Comment: not showing any value

Comment: If tag has no value, it'll do the else block. Figure it out this is basic stuff.

Comment: Just make sure _bookmarkbtn has a value.

Comment: that is where i think got wrong

Comment: As i said, did you connect the button? Tip: add a `assert(_bookmarkbtn);` in viewDidLoad to avoid future mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
- (IBAction)bookmarkAction:(id)sender 
{
    if ( _bookmarkbtn.tag)
    {
          [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          _bookmarkbtn.tag = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
          [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          _bookmarkbtn.tag = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the tag after the event? Are you trying to make a toggle button?

Answer (score 2):

First set button selected image and normal images.

```
        [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"]
           forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"]
           forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

and change the status of the button to selected when button pressed.
Check sender tag with your _bookmarkbtn tag.

```
  - (IBAction)bookmarkAction:(id)sender {

       if ( _bookmarkbtn.tag == sender.tag)

      {
         _bookmarkbtn.selected = !_bookmarkbtn.selected;
     }

}
```

Comment: When i use this statement if ( _bookmarkbtn.tag == sender.tag) it gives me error Property tag not found on object of type strong id and then i  defined bool BOOL isSelected; and used if (  _bookmarkbtn.isSelected ==YES) but still not working.